# Cakephp Paginate Find

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I want to list the posts of a given user.  It work but paginate is not accurate.

My code is the following

```
public function index($userid = null) {

     if ($this->Post->exists($userid)) {

        $this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$userid))), 
            $this->paginate());

        } else
        {

        $this->Post->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
    }
```

The result give the correct list -->   3 posts,  but the paginator display page number 1 and 2

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Refer to the documentation

The code in the question is quite confused.

#### find

The [find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) method only has two parameters:

> find(string $type = 'first', array $params = array())

The third parameter (the result of calling paginate) isn't used and will be ignored - but it *will* setup the view variables for the pagination helper, based on the conditions used in the paginate call - there are no conditions being used.

It is not possible to paginate the result of a find call - to do so restructure the code to call paginate instead of find.

#### paginate

The [paginate](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html#_paginate) method is just a [proxy](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L1067) for the [paginator component](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-PaginatorComponent.html#_paginate) - it can be used in several ways, this one (controller code example):

> $this->paginate($conditions)

Is the most appropriate usage for the case in the question i.e. the complete action code should be similar to:

```
public function index($userId = null) {
    $conditions = array();
    if ($userId) {
        $conditions['Post.user_id'] = $userId;
    }
    $this->set('posts',$this->paginate($conditions));
}
```

Note that logically, if a user id is requested that doesn't exist the response should be nothing - not everything.

Comment: @bowlerae neither of which are duplicated by this answer ;)

Comment: I wanted to vote for both responses, but the system does not allow it. I can only vote for 1 solution,  sorry.  And thanks to both of you

Comment: Actually yea I'm a little upset. I worked hard to provide a correct answer in a timely manner, pointing out one issue that neither other answer points out, explaining the error in find vs paginate just as you have done, as well as provide explanation to the user. I took out 2 sentences you might deem as "rant" but yet I don't understand why this answer was accepted over the other two.

Comment: @bowlerae To address rant: First off, your answer focuses on the person, not the code. There is a huge amount of "you" in it. Second, it's very accusative. `</end simulated rant>`. Note that this text is based on your answer. I chose to answer because _neither_ existing reply clarified that you _can_ pass conditions directly to paginate or made it clear that it is not possible to call find and paginate in some combination. OTOH multiple answers are to be expected. I recommend asking on meta if you still have some concerns/doubts, I appreciate you clarifying your motives though.

Comment: "you can pass conditions directly to paginate or made it clear that it is not possible to call find and paginate in some combination." both johnniedoe and I explained how to pass conditions to paginate. And I also pointed out the flaw in using both find and paginate but only displaying the find.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that conditions for paginate do now work that way.

If you want to set conditions for paginations you should do it as follows:

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('Post.user_id' => $userid)));
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
```

And yes, the result stored in `$posts` ( in view ) will be proper as you assigned proper find result to it, meanwhile you've paginated post model without any conditions whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're checking to see if the post exists but using the `$userid`. Are you trying to see "if the user exists, get the posts for that user, or else get posts for ALL users"? As you have it right now, say you have the `$userid = 159`, but the `max Post.id in your database is 28`, then the condition is not being met because it is checking to see whether or not there is a `Post with the id = 159` that exists, which it doesn't.

Second, your conditions are wrong. You are performing a find and then a paginate which are two separate queries. The conditions are being implemented on the find query but not the paginate but you are only displaying the find results.

```
public function index($userid = null) {
    // setting recursive outside of if statement makes it applicable either way
    $this->Post->recursive = 0;

    // check if user exists
    if ($this->Post->User->exists($userid)) {
        // get posts for user
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post', array('Post.user_id' => $userid));
    }
    else{
        // get all posts
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
    }    

} // end index function
```

Comment: I'd upvote your answer for pointing out the userid logic error - but there's too much rant in it =).

Comment: Thanks, you code is working fine. Actually, when a non-user click on the link to run index function, he's got all the posts and when he is connected, he's got the list of his own posts. That's what I wanted to do.  Userid contains the id of the connected user.

Comment: @AD7six lol had to give explanation, not rant....took out some of my "explanation" :)

Comment: If that is what you want user2402436, then you can check if the user is logged in and then use the condition `'Post.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')`